# Any Generic Design pattern available for Order Management

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

This is more of a design question.

In various projects I keep seeing different implementations and design to handle the same issue/requirement

Requirement: Order Management to handle New Install, Supplement Order, Change Order and Delete Order
Most complexity comes around order supplement, where we have to handle changes made by users on the fly.

This is a generic issue with nearly all order management system but I tried researching the best practice around these requirements to have a direction to have a generic framework to handle this.

Comment: What is your question? PS [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

[image]

Put all your business code/logic of Order Management into the `Entities` layer and `Use Cases` layer, then reuse them somewhere you need.